# Find minutes working alone

Tags: php, time, schedule

I have list of times for staff. I need to find out if any of the staff was working alone and how many minutes they were working alone for the day

```
| staff| start | end   |
|:---  |:---   |:---   |
| 1    | 11:05 | 20:00 | 
| 2    | 11:00 | 17:00 |
| 3    | 19:00 | 03:00 |
| 4    | 13:00 | 20:00 |
| 5    | 19:00 | 03:00 |
```

With Andrea help, following is the code that gets the first and last person who was working alone with alone minutes, but its not quiet right. Because if there was 3 people with different times that worked alone, it will give problem.

```
$staff = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$start = array("11:05", "11:00", "19:00", "13:00", "19:00");
$end = array("20:00", "17:00", "03:00", "20:00", "03:05");

array_multisort($start, $end, $staff);

$aloneStart = (strtotime($start[1]) - strtotime($start[0]))/60; // first and second items are the ones that may be working alone at start
$aloneEnd = (strtotime($end[count($end)-1]) - strtotime($end[count($end)-2]))/60; // last and second to last are the ones that may be working alone at end
if($aloneStart > 0){
  $staffAloneStart = $staff[0]; //must be the first who worked alone  
  echo "minutes alone at start: " . $aloneStart . " and it was " . $staffAloneStart . "\n";
} 
if($aloneEnd > 0){
  $staffAloneEnd = $staff[count($end)-1]; // must be the last to end that worked alone  
  echo "minutes alone at end: " . $aloneEnd . " and it was " . $staffAloneEnd . "\n";
} 
$aloneTime = intval($aloneStart)+intval($aloneEnd);
echo "total time alone " . $aloneTime;
```

with following array, you will see the minutes for first user needs to be more then 5 minutes, because he is working alone more at evening.

```
$staff = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$start = array("11:05", "11:10", "19:00", "13:00", "19:00");
$end = array("20:00", "17:00", "03:00", "16:00", "03:00");
```

Comment: Yes: How much research effort is expected of [Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @RiggsFolly I dont need solution, I just need little guidance on how to implement this.

Comment: Is this stored in a database, or just an array?

Comment: @Qirel  database, but fetching and making into array.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to create a list of events

```
Staff   Event Time
1       S     11:05
1       E     20:00
2       S     11:00
2       E     17:00 etc.
```

Then sort them in time order and iterate through the events.

If a person starts a shift then add one to a staffOnShift variable, if it is an end then subtract one.

If the staffOnShift == 1 && the event is a shift start then add the minutes since the last event to the minutesAlone variable.

Hope this helps you to get started.

**Additional explanation**

Yes, the start and end need to be treated as separate events so after sorting you would have a list like

```
Staff   S/E   Time       staffOnShift       minutesAlone
2        S    11:00           1               0
1        S    11:05           2               5
4        S    13:00           3               5
2        E    17:00           2               5
3        S    19:00           3               5
5        S    19:00           4               5
1        E    20:00           3               5
4        E    20:00           2               5
3        E    03:00           1               5
5        E    03:00           0               5 + 0 = 5
```

Iterate through this list and add when someone starts a shift and subtract when someone’s shift ends, this will give you the number of people on shift at each event, I have put it in column 4.

If staffOnShift == 1 (before the add or subtract), add the minutes since the last event to the minutesAlone variable. (This isnt quite what I said above but the logic table helped to clarify)

With your data the only events to meet those criteria are the second and last. So 5 minutes would be added because there is 1 person on shift at the start. The criteria are met at the end as well but as there are no minutes between the last two events it would not add to the total.

Comment: sorry, it is still not very clear.  you have added start end ending time in separate rows and marked them with `s` and `e`. If shift starts, then start adding, until it ends?

Comment: One thing is tho, I need to find out which staff worked alone for the day. I'm thinking how can I differentiate which staff's worked alone in the whole day

Comment: The staff number is in the data in column 1 so you know who worked alone

Comment: Yes, the first column which has staff id

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

It took some time but I found a solution.
It does have one extra item in the array but since the duration is zero it shouldn't cause an issue.

```
$staff = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$start = array("11:05", "11:00", "19:00", "13:00", "19:00");
$end = array("16:00", "17:00", "03:00", "16:00", "03:05");

// Add staff number to end of time ex 11:00 => 11:00#2
For($i=0; $i<count($start);$i++){
    $start[$i] .= "#" . $staff[$i];
    $end[$i] .= "#" . $staff[$i];

}
$t = array_merge($start,$end); // create one long array with all in and out times
sort($t);

// Multisport is needed to get all arrays in time order as reference
array_multisort($start, $end, $staff);

// Find first start time (11:00) and slice array thwre, build string
$test = implode(PHP_EOL,array_slice($t, array_search($start[0], $t)));

// Find the times before first start (night end times) and add them last in string
$test .= PHP_EOL . implode(PHP_EOL,array_slice($t, 0,array_search($start[0], $t)));
$times = explode(PHP_EOL, $test); // explode to make it array again
 // Var_dump($times);

$WhoIsInDaHouse = array("dummy"); // add a dummy variable since 0=false in later if
$j=0;
for($i=0; $i<count($times);$i++){
    $TimePerson = explode("#", $times[$i]);
    $Time = $TimePerson[0];
    $person = $TimePerson[1];


    $inout = array_search($person, $WhoIsInDaHouse); //is person in house and about to leave?
    If($inout != false){ //if person enter work false, if true: key of person leaving in $WhoIsInDaHouse
        //Here $person is leaving work
        Unset($WhoIsInDaHouse[$inout]);

        If(count($WhoIsInDaHouse) == 2){ // someone will now be alone since we have a dummy
            $Alone[$j]["start"] = $Time;
            $Alone[$j]["who"] = array_slice($WhoIsInDaHouse, -1)[0];
        }elseif(count($WhoIsInDaHouse) == 1 && $prevcount == 2){
            // Only dummy left
            $Alone[$j]["end"] = $Time;
            $Alone[$j]["duration"] = strtotime($Alone[$j]["end"])-strtotime($Alone[$j]["start"]);
            $j++;
        }
    }Else{
        // Here person enters work
        $WhoIsInDaHouse[] = $person;

        If(count($WhoIsInDaHouse) == 2){ // someone is entering alone
            $Alone[$j]["start"] = $Time;
            $Alone[$j]["who"] = $person;
        }elseif(count($WhoIsInDaHouse)>2 && $prevcount == 2){ // not alone anymore
            $Alone[$j]["end"] = $Time;
            $Alone[$j]["duration"] = strtotime($Alone[$j]["end"])-strtotime($Alone[$j]["start"]);
            $j++;
        }
    }
    $prevcount = count($WhoIsInDaHouse);
}
Var_dump($Alone);
```

And see the beauty run https://3v4l.org/dCL2H

It took me a long time to figure out I needed a dummy. Who knew a dummy could be useful?

Comment: with your solution, can I find out which staff worked alone on the shift, rather than just checking alone time only?

Comment: @Basit So you need the staff number?

Comment: Yes, the person who worked alone in the shift with duration he worked alone. `Andreas worked 4 min alone` - `Basit worked 10  min alone` like this..  group by staff i guess.

Comment: @Basit Try the updated code.

Comment: wouldn't this code will break, if 3 people work alone in different times of the day?

Comment: Would this code handle the situation where a staff member was alone in mid shift, if number 3 did not get on shift until 21:00.

Comment: Im working on it but it's very hard to figure out the logic of it.

Comment: Ya, I have been completely puzzled by it.

Comment: @Basit I can't do it. This is how far I have come so far you (or anyone else) can take it from here https://3v4l.org/rof73 I think the issue I got is the who leaves work. Need to spend time with the family

Comment: @Basit after family time it was shower time and suddenly I realised I had forgotten $i++ in the code. With $i++ inside the else{} the alone array starts to fill up. Not correct but it's getting there I think

Comment: @Andreas where should I put `$i++`?

Comment: I have created another question adding your answer on it on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45134858/staff-schedule-working-alone-minutes — since this question was not specific enough, so it got blocked by the system.

Comment: @Basit I found a solution I posted it in the other thread and updated this answer.