# Staff schedule working alone minutes

Tags: php, datetime, time, schedule, calculation

I have list of times for staff. I need to find out if any of the staff was working alone and how many minutes they were working alone for the day

```
| staff| start | end   |
|:---  |:---   |:---   |
| 1    | 11:05 | 20:00 | 
| 2    | 11:00 | 17:00 |
| 3    | 19:00 | 03:00 |
| 4    | 13:00 | 20:00 |
| 5    | 19:00 | 03:00 |
```

With [Andreas' help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45132005/2943403), following is the code that gets the first and last person who was working alone with alone minutes, but its not quite right. Because if there were 3 people with different times that worked alone, it will give a problem. https://3v4l.org/6OmjO

```
$staff = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$start = array("11:05", "11:00", "19:00", "13:00", "19:00");
$end = array("20:00", "17:00", "03:00", "20:00", "03:05");

array_multisort($start, $end, $staff);

$aloneStart = (strtotime($start[1]) - strtotime($start[0])) / 60; // first and second items are the ones that may be working alone at start
$aloneEnd = (strtotime($end[count($end) - 1]) - strtotime($end[count($end) - 2])) / 60; // last and second to last are the ones that may be working alone at end

if ($aloneStart > 0)
{
    $staffAloneStart = $staff[0]; //must be the first who worked alone
    echo "minutes alone at start: " . $aloneStart . " and it was " . $staffAloneStart . "\n";
}

if ($aloneEnd > 0)
{
    $staffAloneEnd = $staff[count($end) - 1]; // must be the last to end that worked alone
    echo "minutes alone at end: " . $aloneEnd . " and it was " . $staffAloneEnd . "\n";
}

$aloneTime = intval($aloneStart) + intval($aloneEnd);
echo "total time alone " . $aloneTime;
```

with following array, you will see the minutes for first user needs to be more then 5 minutes, because he is working alone more at evening.

```
$staff = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$start = array("11:05", "11:10", "19:00", "13:00", "19:00");
$end = array("20:00", "17:00", "03:00", "16:00", "03:00");
```

Comment: @mickmackusa adding date is not a problem, is the calculation that I'm puzzled with. Since we have to track all the staff, which may have worked alone times for the shift and count the minutes he/she worked alone..

Comment: @mickmackusa The way I understood his two questions, the output should be something that tells him who has been alone and for how long. How you present it is probably not so important since he seems to be able to change your output to what he wants anyway. I may be wrong, but that is how I understood Basit. Also he has many qustions and answers in PHP, so I think he can handle any output you give him.

Comment: looking forward eagerly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am doing a complete re-write of my answer so that it is clear and flows in the proper order.  I made a couple of minor refinements from my previous method, but nothing drastic.

First is the data preparation code.  I convert the OP's `hh:mm` time in and out values to simple minute values, while maintaining employee ids as keys.

```
// My test data in OP's format to start with:
$staff=[1,2,3];
$start=['11:00','13:00','17:00'];
$end=['21:00','15:00','19:00'];

// My data preparation method:
foreach($staff as $i=>$v){
    $on=explode(':',$start[$i]);  // separate hh from mm of start of shift
    $on_minutes=$on[0]*60+$on[1];  // calculate total minutes from start of day
    $off=explode(':',$end[$i]);   // separate hh from mm of end of shift
    $off_minutes=($off[0]+($on[0]>$off[0]?24:0))*60+$off[1];  // calculate minutes from start of day, factoring shift that run past midnight
    $shifts[$v]=[$on_minutes,$off_minutes];  // store prepared data for future processes
}
/*
  (new prepared array):
  $shifts=[
    1=>[660,1260],
    2=>[780,900],
    3=>[1020,1140]
  ];
*/
```

This is the data processing snippet.  I have built in a shortcut -- if one employee shares an identical shift with another employee, then the first employee is immediately deemed to have zero minutes alone (obviously).  Otherwise, an employee's shift is compared one by one against the other employees' shifts to determine how many minutes they are alone.

```
function whittle($colleague_shifts,$pieces_of_shift){  // initially, PoS is only one element
    foreach($colleague_shifts as $k=>$cs){
        foreach($pieces_of_shift as $i=>$ps){
            if($cs[0]<=$ps[0] && $cs[1]>=$ps[1]){
                unset($pieces_of_shift[$i]);
                continue;  // fully covered by coworker
            }
            $temp=[];
            if($ps[0]<$cs[0] && $cs[0]<$ps[1]){
                $temp[]=[$ps[0],$cs[0]];    // push new unmatched start into temp PoS array
            }
            if($ps[1]>$cs[1] && $cs[1]>$ps[0]){
                $temp[]=[$cs[1],$ps[1]];    // push new unmatched end into temp PoS array
            }
            if($temp){
                array_splice($pieces_of_shift,$i,1,$temp);  // replace the current PoS with 1 or 2 new PoS subarrays
            }
        }
        if(!$pieces_of_shift){
            return 0;  // no minutes alone
        }
    }
    // subtract all end alone minutes from all start alone minutes
    return array_sum(array_column($pieces_of_shift,1))-array_sum(array_column($pieces_of_shift,0));
}

foreach($shifts as $id=>$s){
    $colleague_shifts=array_diff_key($shifts,[$id=>'']);  // generate array excluding target worker's shift
    if(in_array($s,$colleague_shifts)){  // check for same start and end times elsewhere
        $alone[$id]=0;  // exact duplicate allows shortcut as "never alone"
    }else{
        $alone[$id]=whittle($colleague_shifts,[$s]);  // whittle down times where target employee is alone
    }
}
var_export($alone);
```

Output:

```
array (
  1 => 360,  // alone from 11am-1pm, 3pm-5pm, and 7pm-9pm
  2 => 0,   // never alone
  3 => 0,   // never alone
)
```

To help you follow what is happening inside of `whittle()`

- Staff #1 starts with a full shift from `660` to `1260`. (`$pieces_of_shift` is an array with just one subarray with two elements - start minutes and end minutes)
  `$pieces_of_shift=[[660,1260]];`
- After being compared against Staff #2, the original `$pieces_of_shift` subarray is replaced by two new subarrays -- the alone time at the start of the shift, and the alone time at the end of the shift: `660` to `780` and `900` to `1260`.
  `$pieces_of_shift=[[660,780],[900,1260]];`
- Then Staff #3's shift is compared against both of Staff #1's two remaining ranges of alone time.  Staff #3's shift doesn't overlap any part of the first subarray, but it does in the second.  This means the second range of time is then replaced to effectively "punch out" the overlap in shift time.
  `$pieces_of_shift=[[660,780],[900,1020],[1140,1260]];`
- This results in Staff #1's shift have 3 periods of "alone" time: `660` to `780`, `900` to `1020`, and `1140` to `1260`.  These 3 ranges of alone time (2hrs each) yields 6 hours of total solo work or 360 minutes.

Here is [a demo with additional comments](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ca8e0ae26d8c562f35d763e1841be63acbc37dd2).

---

If there is a high probability or high volume of duplicate shifts in a particular batch, total iterations inside of `whittle()` can be reduced by writing `$colleague_shifts=array_map('unserialize', array_unique(array_map('serialize', $shifts)))` before the first `foreach()` loop.

For that matter, the same multi-functional approach *could* be used to shortcut several duplicate shifts before the call of `foreach($shifts...)`, but I have chosen not to implement that approach because it may not be worth the convolution.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your "times". If I was to convert them back to "normal" would this be correct? https://3v4l.org/f0s9u Just to make sure I got the first line of code correct. And 27 = 03:00 next day.

Comment: it has gone very quiet from OP. I'm also just wondering if anything is wrong with our answers. Both of them seems to work. And I don't think there is much performance difference. It's just a matter of output as far as I can see

Comment: @Andreas sorry guys, was traveling for past 2 days.. going to test both today and implement the one that can be easily breakdown into small functions or something.. have to do phpunit test also for it.  But regardless... I really appreciate help.

Comment: @mickmackusa I'm getting error `Warning: Illegal offset type in test.php on line 24`  with following array initial values https://gist.github.com/iBasit/b18457f6bed6145827292fd02eb57512

Comment: It is really hard to accept two answers from both great contributors. I want to thank you both of you.  @mickmackusa, thank you for explaination for step by step. I will be going through on all of them and try different values and fix any problem.

Comment: Do you use the preparation method?

Comment: @mickmackusa I agree, that's why I'm implementing yours, while I'm learning each step on how you did it. Thank you

Comment: @mickmackusa I'm curious why are you passing `$pieces_of_shift` as an array? cause it can be without the array no?

Comment: Passing `$pieces_of_shift` as an indexed array containing a two-element array affords consistency throughout the whittling process.  The start-end pairs/chunks are seamlessly looped & compared via if-statements against the coworkers' shifts (which are in the same format) and `array_splice()` conditionally replaces the chunk with one or two new elements -- maintaining loop simplicity.  If you passed the `start` and `end` values as integers, you would have to generate an array for workers with multiple periods of alone time.  I am open to different approaches; I may misunderstand your question.

Comment: @Basit Can you better explain what your alternative call/method might look like?  I'm happy to give feedback.  I want what you want -- the best possible code.

Comment: `$alone[$id]=whittle($colleague_shifts,[$s]);` if you check the second parameter it is further turn into more array `[$s]`, but I think it can be done with simpe `$s` alone, Since it will never be passed more then 1 array and just function will remove the second foreach to further refine. but overall it works great.

Comment: Okay I think I know what you are getting at (if not, please don't lose patience, and try to re-explain).  So are you saying, considering the second bulletpoint in my answer, that you would prefer to have a 1-dim array with four elements `['660','780','900','1260']` instead of a multi-dim with [['660','780'],['900','1260']]`?  That would serve to simply a step to deem a whole shift covered, if the next employee worked e.g. `600` to `1320`, but I could code that short cut with multi-dim too. I think an array of arrays is more comprehensible, but I'll play with an alternative for you.

Comment: @Basit Actually, now that I'm mulling it over, the 1-dim array of pieces could get muddle up if  the next employee worked, say, `700` to `740`.  Would the new 1-dim array look like then?  How would you keep the paired/chunked elements in order and not mess up the alone versus not-alone distinctions?

Comment: The minute calculation at the end of the function would need to subtract every "2nd value" from every "1st value" in a foreach loop or something.  I am keeping these `pieces` in chunks for ease of handling throughout.

Answer (score 1):

Got it!

It took some time but I found a solution.
Managed to find a solution to mickmacks test case.
Here is a ten person case and it seems to hold up for that too.

```
<?php
$staff = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
$start = array("11:00", "13:00", "17:00", "17:00", "11:00", "13:30", "16:50", "18:30","17:00", "11:00");
$end = array("21:00", "15:00", "19:00", "19:30", "11:30", "15:10", "18:45", "19:45", "19:00", "11:30");

// Add staff number to end of time ex 11:00 => 11:00#2
For($i=0; $i<count($start);$i++){
    $start[$i] .= "#" . $staff[$i];
    $end[$i] .= "#" . $staff[$i];

}
$t = array_merge($start,$end); // create one long array with all in and out times
sort($t);
//var_dump($t);
// Multisport is needed to get all arrays in time order as reference
array_multisort($start, $end, $staff);

// Find first start time (11:00) and slice array thwre, build string
$test = implode(PHP_EOL,array_slice($t, array_search($start[0], $t)));

// Find the times before first start (night end times) and add them last in string
$test .= PHP_EOL . implode(PHP_EOL,array_slice($t, 0,array_search($start[0], $t)));
$times = explode(PHP_EOL, $test); // explode to make it array again
 // Var_dump($times);

$WhoIsInDaHouse = array("dummy"); // add a dummy variable since 0=false in later if
$j=0;
for($i=0; $i<count($times);$i++){
    //echo $times[$i] ." " . $i ."\n";
    if($times[$i]){
        $TimePerson = explode("#", $times[$i]);
        $Time = $TimePerson[0];
        $person = $TimePerson[1];


        $inout = array_search($person, $WhoIsInDaHouse); //is person in house and about to leave?
        If($inout != false){ //if person enter work false, if true: key of person leaving in $WhoIsInDaHouse
            //Here $person is leaving work
            Unset($WhoIsInDaHouse[$inout]);

            If(count($WhoIsInDaHouse) == 2){ // someone will now be alone since we have a dummy
                $Alone[$j]["start"] = $Time;
                $Alone[$j]["who"] = array_slice($WhoIsInDaHouse, -1)[0];
            }elseif(count($WhoIsInDaHouse) == 1 && $prevcount == 2){
                // Only dummy left
                $Alone[$j]["end"] = $Time;
                $Alone[$j]["duration"] = strtotime($Alone[$j]["end"])-strtotime($Alone[$j]["start"]);
                $j++;
            }
        }Else{
            // Here person enters work
            $WhoIsInDaHouse[] = $person;

            If(count($WhoIsInDaHouse) == 2){ // someone is entering alone
                $Alone[$j]["start"] = $Time;
                $Alone[$j]["who"] = $person;
            }elseif(count($WhoIsInDaHouse)>2 && $prevcount == 2){ // not alone anymore
                $Alone[$j]["end"] = $Time;
                $Alone[$j]["duration"] = strtotime($Alone[$j]["end"])-strtotime($Alone[$j]["start"]);
                $j++;
            }
        }
        $prevcount = count($WhoIsInDaHouse);
    }
}
foreach($Alone as $key => &$loner){
    if($loner["duration"]==0) unset($Alone[$key]);
}
Var_dump($Alone);
```

And see the beauty run https://3v4l.org/bT2bZ

It took me a long time to figure out I needed a dummy. Who knew a dummy could be useful?

Comment: And the reason there is an extra item in the array is because I have two people starting at the same time. So thefore one is alone but since the next starts at the same time the duration is zero.

Comment: Somehow this simple thing became very hard to do lol, even myself still stuck on finding a simple solution for this.

Comment: @mickmackusa Wow... That is odd. It seems the for loop runs one time to much. If I echo $times[$i] it echoes one empty. If I stop the loop one run early it worked on your example but not on five persons. So something odd was happening. I just added a if($times[$i]) and that seems to dea with the problem. Thanks for pointing it out! :-)